# Handling TestNG asserts in selenium

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In previous versions tester could verify or assert something. Now we can only use assert and when the problem exists whole test is failed.

Please, help how to handle asserts so they don't make test to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably have your own verify methods, which would catch the AssertionErrors, append them to a list of errors and in the aftermethods, that TestNG provides list them and mark the tc as failed..if the list is not empty.

@Coretek : Asserts are the commands which make the whole test break instantly and not verify.  Verify is supposed to continue execution even if the test fails. (in old Selenium way :) )

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of assert use 
`try{...} 
catch(Exception e){}`

But I thought verify was the command which let the whole test instantly break if one verify was false.
`assert` or `assertEqueals` (in JUnit) lets the test go on and you can have more assert errors in the result of one testcase.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "soft assert" approach, like the one suggested [here](http://beust.com/weblog/2009/06/25/soft-asserts/)?